# Using Drupal 6's form ahah to have one dropdown field update the values of a second dropdown field

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am working on a pair of form fields the directly effect one another. Specifically the problem I am dealing with is that we have thousands of groups users can join on this website that I have been working on. We are creating some administrative analytics forms for the site. Part of those forms is filtering by group.

The problem is that most of the people don't know the name of a group off the top of their heads, only what it starts with. So instead of using auto-complete we came up with two dropdowns. The first contains the options A through Z, letters of the alphabet which the group names begin with. The second dropdown contains all of the groups beginning with the selected letter.

The concept is simple enough and we were able to implement the AJAX pretty easy with jQuery. But this causes validation errors. After some research I found that this has to do with Drupal form caching. The solution is to use the ahah functions.

The problem with that is that all the instructions I have found so far deal with ahah actions for the specified field updating itself, not another field. So I am trying to figure out how to get the list of letters to update the group list using ahah and registering the new values with the form cache.

One solution I found was to simply load all the values on the page in a hidden dropdown and then just load up those in the set in the visible one as needed. But that creates a bunch of problems because the client uses almost exclusively IE and we have seen IE choke when given huge lists like that. Especially with the lists stored in JavaScript. So we need a light-weight solution.

Any thoughts? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the answer on another StackExchange site. His suggestion to use the example module to come up with the solution worked very well.

Solution found here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35048/using-drupal-6s-form-ahah-to-have-one-dropdown-field-update-the-values-of-a-sec

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell AHAH works like this:

- Form gets generated with an empty `$form_state`
- When an element that has the `#ahah` property gets changed an ajax call is made to the url specified as path in the `#ahah` property.
- The callback at that url does this:

  - Retrieves the form from the form cache
  - Processes the form
  - Rebuilds the form with a current `$form_state` so that it can add / change elements based on that
  - The form is put in the form cache to avoid validation errors
  - The form is rendered and returned as JSON
- Drupal replaces the contents of the wrapper div with the new form.

In your case you'll need to make your form generation function aware of the values selected in $form_state. It would have to:

- Generate the letters drop-down
- Look into $form_state and see if there is a letter selected. If so, generate the second drop-down based on the selected value.

The callback function would implement the form caching and rebuilding.

There are good explanations with code for the callback function here:

- http://drupal.org/node/348475
- http://drupal.org/node/331941

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth description of how it works. I really appreciate all the info and help.